# Regular expressions error when trying to deploy Sagemaker OD model

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I am following this tutorial to try and deploy my own previously trained model, which I have artifacts for in a tar.gc file, stored in an S3 bucket (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/object-detection-and-model-retraining-with-amazon-sagemaker-and-amazon-augmented-ai/)

Everything seems to run fine until I get to this point in the code:

```
# deploying the model into one ml.m4.xlarge instance
object_detector = model.deploy(initial_instance_count = 1,
                               instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge',
                               endpoint_name = endpoint_name)
```

Which spits out this error for me:

`ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: 2 validation errors detected: Value 'model.tar.gz-2021-08-26-08-43-29-384' at 'modelName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*; Value '685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/object-detection:1' at 'primaryContainer.modelDataUrl' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(https|s3)://([^/]+)/?(.*)$`

I checked the attributes which it seems to refer to and they are:

```
model.model_data
```

`'685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/object-detection:1'`

and

```
model.name
```

`'model.tar.gz-2021-08-26-08-43-29-384'`

But I'm not sure what the issue is supposed to be. Earlier in the demo it seems to want to copy the tar.gc file from the output location to another, and I don't understand the significance of that. Can't it just stay where it is in /output? I just copied it to one sub-directory below the folder it was deposited into after training, if that helps. e.g. S3/folder/output -> S3/folder/output/model/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but the errors you get seems to be pretty clear. The model name cannot contain dots looking at the expected regex, I don't know where does it come from, but using a filename seems to be not allowed. The second error is similar, the model URL has to start with a networking protocol like `https` or `S3`. Look at the rest of the code or where this things are defined.

Comment: thanks. this is exactly how those things are formatted in the tutorial link, so i'm not sure what they should even be changed to

Comment: I think that for pre-built models sagemaker stores the model name somewhere, this don't happen for your custom model, so you could try to explicitly set a model name using `name=yournamewithoutdots` as parameter in your `model.Model` function ..  the same specifying `model_data=your model s3 location`.. Look [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html#model)